# Producer-Consumer, Bounded Buffer Insert Error?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, mutex, producer-consumer

I am attempting to do an assignment that requires having multiple producers and consumers producing and consuming random integers in a bounded buffer. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.nio.Buffer;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ProducerConsumer 
{   
    interface Buffer
    {
        public abstract void insert(int item);
        public abstract int remove();
    }

    static class BoundedBuffer implements Buffer
    {
        private static final int maxSize = 5;

        private Semaphore mutex;
        private Semaphore empty;
        private Semaphore full;

        private int count;
        private int in;
        private int out;
        private int[] buffer;
        //private ArrayList<Integer> buffer = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        public BoundedBuffer()
        {
            mutex = new Semaphore(1);
            empty = new Semaphore(5);
            full = new Semaphore(0);

            count = 0;
            in = 0;
            out = 0;
        }

        public synchronized int remove()
        {
            int  item = 0;

            while (count == 0)
            {

            }

            try{
                full.acquire();
                mutex.acquire();
            }catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("REMOVAL ERROR: " + e);
            }

            count--;
            item = buffer[out];
            out = (out+1) % maxSize;

            System.out.println("      Consumer consumed: " + item);

            mutex.release();
            empty.release();

            return item;
        }

        public synchronized void insert(int item)
        {
            while (count == maxSize)
            {

            }

            try{
                empty.acquire();
                mutex.acquire();
            }catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("INSERTION ERROR: " + e);
            }

            count++;
            buffer[in] = item;
            in = (in+1) % maxSize;

            System.out.println("Producer produced " + item);

            mutex.release();
            full.release();
        }
    }

    static class Producer implements Runnable
    {
        private Buffer buffer;

        public Producer(Buffer b)
        {
            buffer = b;
        }

        public void run()
        {
            Random proRand = new Random();
            Random sleepRand = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(sleepRand.nextInt((500 - 0) + 0));
                }catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println("PRODUCER INTERRUPT: " + e);
                }

                buffer.insert(proRand.nextInt((99999 - 10000) + 10000));
            }

        }
    }

    static class Consumer implements Runnable
    {
        private Buffer buffer;

        public Consumer(Buffer b)
        {
            buffer = b;
        }

        public void run()
        {
            Random sleepRand = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(sleepRand.nextInt((500 - 0) + 0));
                }catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println("CONSUMER INTERRUPT: " + e);
                }

                buffer.remove();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int sleepTime = scanner.nextInt();
        int numPro = scanner.nextInt();
        int numCon = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.close();

        System.out.println("Using arguments from command line");
        System.out.println("Sleep time = " + sleepTime);
        System.out.println("Producer threads = " + numPro);
        System.out.println("Consumer threads = " + numCon);
        System.out.println();

        Buffer shared = new BoundedBuffer();

        /* proThread = new Thread(new Producer(shared));
        Thread conThread = new Thread(new Consumer(shared));

        proThread.start();
        conThread.start();*/


        ExecutorService proPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numPro);
        for (int i = 0; i < numPro; i++)
        {
            proPool.submit(new Producer(shared));

        }
        proPool.shutdown();

        ExecutorService conPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numCon);
        for (int i = 0; i < numCon; i++)
        {
            conPool.submit(new Consumer(shared));
        }
        conPool.shutdown();

        try{
            if (!proPool.awaitTermination(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
            {
                proPool.shutdownNow();
            }
        }catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("TERMINATION ERROR: " + e);
        }

        try{
            if (!conPool.awaitTermination(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
            {
                conPool.shutdownNow();
            }
        }catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("TERMINATION ERROR: " + e);
        }

        /*for (int i = 0; i < numPro; i++)
        {
            Runnable produce = new Producer();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numCon; i++)
        {
            Runnable consume = new Consumer();
        }*/

        //Runnable produce = new Producer();
        //Runnable consume = new Consumer();

        //Thread pro = new Thread(produce, "pro");
        //Thread con = new Thread(consume, "con");
    }

}
```

Right now, I am getting the following output after inputting '20 5 1':

"20 5 1

Using arguments from command line

Sleep time = 20

Producer threads = 5

Consumer threads = 1

INSERTION ERROR: java.lang.InterruptedException

INSERTION ERROR: java.lang.InterruptedException

INSERTION ERROR: java.lang.InterruptedException

REMOVAL ERROR: java.lang.InterruptedException

INSERTION ERROR: java.lang.InterruptedException"

I am a bit confused as to whats causing this. Do I need a different data structure for my bounded buffer?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to spot the following errors:

- int[] buffer is never initialised
- use volatile keyword for "count", "in" and "out"
- do not use "synchronized" when you are already using locks
- the "full" and "empty" Semaphore are not required, remove them
- since you are inserting and removing 100 times with upto 500ms pauses, use at-least 50sec in awaitTermination()

The following version of the program works

```
public static class ProducerConsumer {

        interface Buffer {
            void insert(int item);

            int remove();
        }

        static class BoundedBuffer implements Buffer {

            private static final int maxSize = 5;

            private final int[] buffer = new int[maxSize];

            private final Semaphore mutex;
            private volatile int count;
            private volatile int in;
            private volatile int out;

            //private ArrayList<Integer> buffer = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            public BoundedBuffer() {

                mutex = new Semaphore(1);
                count = 0;
                in = 0;
                out = 0;
            }

            public int remove() {

                int item = 0;

                while (count == 0) {
                }

                try {
                    mutex.acquire();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println("REMOVAL ERROR: " + e);
                }

                count--;
                item = buffer[out];
                out = (out + 1) % maxSize;

                System.out.println("Consumer consumed: " + item);

                mutex.release();

                return item;
            }

            public void insert(int item) {

                while (count == maxSize) {
                }

                try {
                    mutex.acquire();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println("INSERTION ERROR: " + e);
                }

                count++;
                buffer[in] = item;
                in = (in + 1) % maxSize;

                System.out.println("Producer produced " + item);

                mutex.release();
            }
        }

        static class Producer implements Runnable {

            private Buffer buffer;

            public Producer(Buffer b) {
                buffer = b;
            }

            public void run() {

                Random proRand = new Random();
                Random sleepRand = new Random();

                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(sleepRand.nextInt(500));
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        System.out.println("PRODUCER INTERRUPT: " + e);
                    }

                    try {
                        buffer.insert(proRand.nextInt((99999 - 10000) + 10000));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("Error while inserting " + e);
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        static class Consumer implements Runnable {
            private Buffer buffer;

            public Consumer(Buffer b) {
                buffer = b;
            }

            public void run() {

                Random sleepRand = new Random();

                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(sleepRand.nextInt(500));
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        System.out.println("CONSUMER INTERRUPT: " + e);
                    }

                    try {
                        buffer.remove();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("Error while removing " + e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            int sleepTime = 20;
            int numPro = 5;
            int numCon = 1;

            System.out.println("Using arguments from command line");
            System.out.println("Sleep time = " + sleepTime);
            System.out.println("Producer threads = " + numPro);
            System.out.println("Consumer threads = " + numCon);
            System.out.println();

            Buffer shared = new BoundedBuffer();

        /* proThread = new Thread(new Producer(shared));
        Thread conThread = new Thread(new Consumer(shared));

        proThread.start();
        conThread.start();*/

            ExecutorService proPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numPro);
            for (int i = 0; i < numPro; i++) {
                proPool.submit(new Producer(shared));

            }
            proPool.shutdown();

            ExecutorService conPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numCon);
            for (int i = 0; i < numCon; i++) {
                conPool.submit(new Consumer(shared));
            }
            conPool.shutdown();

            try {
                if (!proPool.awaitTermination(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                    proPool.shutdownNow();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("TERMINATION ERROR: " + e);
            }

            try {
                if (!conPool.awaitTermination(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                    conPool.shutdownNow();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("TERMINATION ERROR: " + e);
            }
        }

    }
```